# realloc not allocating memory for next struct

Tags: c, memory, realloc

I need to make an array of structs dynamically and I don't know the size when executing the malloc command. So I thought I could use realloc every time I need another struct! For example this code:

main:

```
    int main(void) {

    flights *flight_list = NULL;
    int numFlights = 0;

    numFlights = load_flights(&flight_list);

    /* output flights. Problem: Only first flight is there, the second is not allocated! */
```

Here's the function:

```
short load_flights(flights **flight_list) {

    flight_list[0] = calloc(1, sizeof(flights));
    flight_list[0]->price = 69;

    flight_list[0] = realloc(*flight_list, sizeof(flights)*2);
    flight_list[1]->price = 70;

    return 2; //num of flights-structs
```

The problem is, that actually 2 elements should be created, but only 1 element is there - check this debugging screenshot:

[image: Debugging Screenshot]

As you can see, `flight_list[0]` is there, but `flight_list[1]` not! But realloc should do the job?

Am I understanding anything wrong?

Comment: With `load_flights(&flight_list)` you are (in a very simplified way) passing a pointer to an array of `flights` *structure objects*. Inside the `load_flights` function you need to dereference the pointer to get the array of objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bug in this line:

```
flight_list[1]->price = 70;
```

Both `[]` and `->` dereference pointers. `a[b]` is equivalent to `*(a+b)` and `a->b` is equivalent to `(*a).b`. Your line therefore means:

```
(**(flight_list + 1)).price = 70;
```

However, `flight_list` (in `load_flights`) is a pointer to the `flight_list` variable in `main`! In the context of `main`, you're computing `&flight_list + 1`, which is an invalid pointer: You're getting the contents of memory that happens to be next to a local variable.

The correct code would be:

```
(*(*flight_list + 1)).price = 70;
```

`*flight_list` is the pointer returned by `realloc`. Here we can step one element ahead in the dynamic array.

We can also write this as:

```
(*flight_list)[1].price = 70;
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! I didn't know that I first have to dereference the pointer and then access the [1]-element! ♥

Comment: @Deduplicator Oops, I forgot my outer pair of parens. Fixed.

Comment: I also thought this, but actually  (*flight_list)[1].price = 70;       works! Now I can access this array element in my main function.

Answer (score -1):

Your `flight_list` is an array of pointers to pointers of flights.

With `flight_list[0] = realloc(*flight_list, sizeof(flights)*2);` you allocate space for two flights to the item `flight_list[0]`, but flight_list itself remains unchanged. In fact, there is no code that allocates any space for `flight_list` at all, but maybe you just left out this code in your example.

If the realloc line of code is what you wanted, you should watch these memory locations in the debugger: `flight_list[0][0]` for the first flight, and `flight_list[0][1]` for the second.

Comment: There are two `flight_list` variables in OP's code. The one in `main` is a pointer to a flight (acts like a dynamic array); the one in `load_flights` is a pointer to a pointer to a flight (acts like the address of a dynamic array). Neither of them is an array of pointers.